# Identifying Execution Plans with Probe Residual

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, execution-plan, xml, plan-cache

I am trying to find out Execution Plans that has `Probe Residual`.

Need to know the following

1. Which physical and logical operator has this `Probe Residual`
2. What is the **Cost%** of that operator in the query
3. Associated Execution plan
4. Query Text

Following is a try that I gave – but I am stuck for getting other details. How to get these details?

Note: I am using SQL Server 2012

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES
(
    DEFAULT 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/showplan'
)
SELECT
    DECP.cacheobjtype,
    DECP.objtype,
    DECP.plan_handle,
    DEQP.objectid,
    DEQP.query_plan,
    DEST.[text]
FROM sys.dm_exec_cached_plans AS DECP
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(DECP.plan_handle) AS DEQP
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(DECP.plan_handle) AS DEST
WHERE
    1 = DEQP.query_plan.exist(
        '//RelOp[
            @PhysicalOp = "Hash Match"
            ]')
```

A **Probe Residual** Example

[image]

References from blogs/articles of Grant Fritchey and Rob Farley below

1. [Probe Residual on Hash Match - Home Of The Scary DBA](http://www.scarydba.com/2011/09/15/probe-residual/)
2. [Probe Residual when you have a Hash Match – a hidden cost in execution plans](http://blogs.lobsterpot.com.au/2011/03/22/probe-residual-when-you-have-a-hash-match-a-hidden-cost-in-execution-plans/)

---

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want to do is to use [nodes() Method (xml Data Type)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188282.aspx) in a cross apply to shred on `RelOp` nodes so you then can use [value() Method (xml Data Type)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178030.aspx) to get the property values you are looking for.

You are specifically looking for the `RelOp` nodes that have a `Hash/ProbeResidual` node so you should use that in a predicate in the XQuery parameter to the `nodes()` function.

```
WITH xmlnamespaces(DEFAULT 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/showplan')
SELECT DEQP.query_plan,
       DEST.text,
       RO.X.value('@PhysicalOp', 'nvarchar(50)') as PhysicalOp,
       RO.X.value('@LogicalOp', 'nvarchar(50)') as LogicalOp,
       RO.X.value('@EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost', 'float') as EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost
FROM sys.dm_exec_cached_plans AS DECP
  CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(DECP.plan_handle) AS DEQP
  CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(DECP.plan_handle) as DEST
  CROSS APPLY DEQP.query_plan.nodes('//RelOp[Hash/ProbeResidual]') as RO(X);
```